# Get variable from previous Tab with Chrome Extentions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, google-chrome-devtools

I open with a chromeextention a new tab and new website. but I need to copy the URL from the previous tab to the new one but I can't get it to work?

What is the best way of doing this? I was looking for using just the clipboard, but in javascript that doesn't work. How can I pass a variable to the new Tab?

**EDIT 1**

popup.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Youtube Downloader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="scripts/background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="download_button" type="button" value="Download MP3"/>
    <br>
    <span id="validation_span"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

MANIFEST

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":"Youtube Downloader",
    "description":"Voor het downloaden van de Youtube muziek",
    "version": "1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",     
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
        ,"http://www.youtube-mp3.org/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : [ "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/*"]
        ,"js" : ["scripts/youtube-mp3.js"]
    }]
}
```

Background.js

```
addEventListener("load", init, false);


//GLOBAL VARIABLES
var succes = 0;
var validation_span;
var button;

function init(event) {
    button = document.getElementById("download_button");
    button.addEventListener("click", getUrl, false);    
}

function getUrl(event){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
        maakLayout(event, tab.url);
    });
}

function maakLayout(event, url) {
    //Layout van de nieuwe View
    validation_span = document.getElementById("validation_span");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.style.width = "300px";
    var br = document.getElementsByTagName("br")[0];
    br.remove();
    button.remove();

    var result = urlValidation(url);

    if(succes == 1){
        validation_span.style.color = "green";
        result = url;
        chrome.tabs.create({"url": "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/nl"}, function(newTab){
        });
    }
    if (succes == 0){
        validation_span.style.color = "red";
    }
    validation_span.innerHTML = result;
}

function urlValidation(url){
    if(url.indexOf('www.youtube.com/watch?v=') >= 0){
        succes = 1;
        return "Url is OK";
    }else{
        succes = 0;
        return "Only Youtube links allowed";
    }
}
```

youtub-mp3.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("Binne");
    if (msg.action == 'url') {
        alert("Message recieved!");
        var copy = msg;
        var inputfield = document.getElementById("youtube-url");
        inputfield.value = copy;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: check EDIT 1 this is my whole application

Comment: When you are saying the previous tab, do you mean the left tab or the previous session/history ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

My original answer won't work because the message will be sent before the content script is has registered the onMessage listener.

I was however able to get it working by using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`:

```
chrome.tabs.create({"url": "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/nl"}, function(newTab) {

    var script = "var inputfield = document.getElementById(\"youtube-url\"); inputfield.value = \"" + url + "\"";
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(newTab.id, { code: script }); 

});
```

You should then be able to remove youtube-mp3.js.

---

If I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, then you just need to make a small change to your code.

In background.js:

```
// your existing code
chrome.tabs.create({"url": "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/nl"}, function(newTab){
    // additional code
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(newTab.id, {action: 'newUrl', url: url});    
});
```

youtube-mp3.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "newUrl")
      // Do whatever you want to do with the url
      console.log(request.url);
  });
```

Comment: no this doesn't work, maybe because the background.js called in the popup.html and not specified in the manifest file?

Comment: That'll teach me to test my own code! :) I've updated my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: nowp still doesn't work, I think the code inside the function doesn't work, because when I set an alert("Test"); in that function that is not executed? how is this possible?